# Why does this multiplication trick work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does this multiplication trick works-- I sort of discovered it on my own.

985 x 974:

(1000 x 1000) - (15 x 1000 + 26 x 1000) + (-15)(-26)

997 x 989:

(1000 x 1000) - (3 x 1000 + 11 x 1000) + (-3)(-11)

1003 x 976:

(1000 x 1000) - (-3 x 1000 + 24 x 1000) + (3)(-24)

1005 x 1007:

(1000 x 1000) - (-5 x 1000 - 7 x 1000) + (5)(7)

Originally I thought about this looking through: https://www.splashlearn.com/blog/best-multiplication-tricks-for-kids/#37-frequently-asked-questions-faqs- (#16 Rounding off to 1000)... I couldn't make sense how they solved their method. Like how they got 990016 (it didn't seem obvious).

So I kept messing with the numbers and eventually created the above method on my own (to make it work). Now I just want to know why it works lol

998 x 992:

(1000 x 1000) - (2 x 1000 + 8 x 1000) + (-2)(-8)

Like the way I came up with it.

I first changed the problem to 1000 x 992

So then I thought 1000 x 1000 - 8 x 1000 would be the same (which I checked)

So then I thought if both were different than a 1000 you would need to do it again. And because they are not 1000 each you need to multiply the difference for the last step (but that's a bit hard for me to visualize).

Like for the basic one:
1000 x 992

(1000 x 1000) - (8 x 1000)  + (0)(-8)

Appreciate any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the distributive property, sometimes called FOIL ("first outers inners last"):
$$(a+b)\cdot (c+d) = a\cdot c + b\cdot c + a\cdot d + b\cdot d.$$
If $b$ and/or $d$ happen to be negative, then you get your earlier results.

You can understand why this works by going back to first principles with multiplication: If $a,b,c$ are integers, then $(a+b)\cdot c$ can be thought of as adding $(a+b)$ to itself $c$ times, which means you add $a$ to itself $c$ times, add $b$ to itself $c$ times, and then add the results: $(a+b)\cdot c = a\cdot c + b\cdot c$.

By the way, an even cleverer application of this is to do something like
$$1025 \cdot 975 = (1000+25)\cdot (1000-25) = 1000\times 1000 - 25\cdot 25.$$

Comment: I understand the algebra. But what I don't see is for example. 985 x 974:

(1000 x 1000) - (15 x 1000 + 26 x 1000) + (-15)(-26). Why do we have (-15)(-26)-- I know it is used to balance off the rounding we made initially 1000 x 1000

Comment: Write $985= 1000-15$ and $974 = 1000-26$.

Comment: Wow very cool I get it! Thanks.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer when you are satisfied.